# Combine the same result mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have result in array of objects and i want to group by the same result in mongoose. For example, I am getting the below result.

```
[ 
  { 
   projectId: 5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024,
   userId: 5c0a29c697e71a0d28b910a9
  },
  { 
   projectId: 5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac,
   userId: 5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa,
  },
  { 
   projectId: 5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024,
   userId: 5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa,
  } 
]
```

Now I want one object for same user and combined projectId's array like below:

```
{
  userId: 5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa, 
  projectId: [
     5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac,
     5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024
  ],
}
```

Please help me, How can i achieve this or suggest me any other thing. Thanks.[image: Attached result]

Comment: You can use [**this**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A06HxAs-30P) aggregation

Comment: Thanks it worked. I want to populate the _id and projectId field. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$userId",
    "projectId": { "$push": "$projectId" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "projects",
    "localField": "projectId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "projectId"
  }}
])
```

Comment: ok could you post all the three documents sample collection. I will show you the working example.

Comment: Please have a look at the above attached screenshot.I used unwined to get the objects, But i want to populate the 2 fields only.

Comment: My above query is working as I can see in your above screen shot. You are getting the data in `user` and `projects` fields. Isn't it? Updated my answer as well. Please test it again

Comment: I mean to say, i want to populate _id, projectName fields from projects field .How can i achieve this?

Comment: That's why I am asking you to post the sample collections from all the documents. Ok do one thing [ask a new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) question with posting all your JSON details. I will surely answer you.

Comment: I am posting you link with a new question.

Comment: Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680441/populate-the-specific-fields-while-using-aggregate-in-mongodb