# Populate specific fields in $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregate to group and populate the result like below:

```
 { 
   "$group": {
     "_id": "$userId",
     "projectId": { "$push": "$projectId" }
    }
 },
 { 
  "$lookup": {
     "from": "users",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
   }
 },
 {   $unwind:"$user" },
 { 
   "$lookup": {
     "from": "projects",
     "localField": "projectId",
     "foreignField": "_id",
     "as": "projects"
    }
 }
```

But i want to **populate specific fields from that result** For this I tried 
 $project, But it combining projectId into one array and projectName into another array.Below is my result json:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa",
    "projectId": [
        "5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac",
        "5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024"
    ],
    "user": {
        "_id": "5c0a29e597e71a0d28b910aa",
        "firstName": "Amit"
        "lastName": "kumar",
        "type": "developer",
        "status": "active"
    },
    "projects": [
        {
            "_id": "5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac",
            "skypeId": "",
            "projectName": "LN-PM",
            "status": "ongoing",
            "assignId": "5c0a2a0a97e71a0d28b910ab"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024",
            "skypeId": "",
            "status": "pending",
            "assignId": "5c0a2a0a97e71a0d28b910ab"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i want to get the only **"firstName and _id"** field from **user** field and **"projectName and _id"** field from the **projects** field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below aggregation with mongodb **3.6** and above

With the newer [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) syntax you can use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)ion inside the [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins) pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$userId",
    "projectId": { "$push": "$projectId" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "userId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$userId" ] }}},
      { "$project": { "firstName": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$user" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "projects",
    "let": { "projectId": "$projectId" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$projectId" ] }}},
      { "$project": { "projectName": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "projects"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, Can you please provide your email so that i can ping you in future regarding mongoDb queries?

Comment: I have one more query. can you help please?