# Get count of a Local field with $lookup mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get the count of local field specific projectId vise.For example i have below documents:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5c0a4efa91b5021228681f7a"),
   "projectId" : ObjectId("5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024"),
   "hours" : 8,
   "__v" : 0
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5c0a4f4191b5021228681f7c"),
   "projectId" : ObjectId("5c0a2a8897e71a0d28b910ac"),
   "hours" : 6,
   "__v" : 0
}

{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5c0a4f4191b5021228681f7d"),
   "projectId" : ObjectId("5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024"),
   "hours" : 2,
   "__v" : 0
}
```

Now, I want to get the hours field count of projectId equals to **5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024**, which is 10.

**Is it possible with $lookup?**

Comment: thanks it worked. But i want to use above query for another collection in another controller in $lookup, which has it's own $match condition. How can i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is used to join two collections. And here you trying to get total counts of `hours` for the specific `projectId`. Therefore, you need to use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) here.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "projectId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5c0a4083753a321c6c4ee024") }}
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$projectId",
    "totalHours": { "$sum": "$hours" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I understood, what you want to say. But i want to use above query in projectController at here: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680441/populate-specific-fields-in-lookup".

Comment: I shared you the url, in which you answered me.

Comment: I am getting projects:[ {_id:null, totalHours:0}]. Should i need to ask another question and provide you it's link?

Comment: Hi @Anthony, I have asked a new question: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704352/get-count-of-specific-field-mongodb"