# How can I populate array of fields by from different collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Please find the query where I am joining 3 collections, and there is a field `assignedPeople`, I just want to populate this field from `Users` collection.

Please find the query,

```
db.parentepics.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { createdBy: ObjectId('613e418f19968b0652bbbb24') } 
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
               from: "childtasklevelones",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "parentEpicId",
               as: "level_1"
             }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
               from: "childtaskleveltwos",
               localField: "level_1._id",
               foreignField: "childTaskLevelOneId",
               as: "level_2"
             }
    }, 
    {
        $lookup: {
               from: "childtasklevelthrees",
               localField: "level_2._id",
               foreignField: "ChildTaskLevelTwoId",
               as: "level_3"
             }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            assignedPeople: 1,
            epicName: 1,
            epicDescription: 1,
            epicPriority: 1,
            startsFrom: 1,
            endsAt: 1,
            createdBy:1,
            levelOne: '$level_1',
            levelTwo: '$level_2',
            levelThree: '$level_3',
        }
    }
])
```

Below is the output of the following query that joins 3 tables. Please find the output.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("615d984e9bd5641c754d2e6e"),
    "assignedPeople" : [
        ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
        ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
    ],
    "epicName" : "AC-EPIC",
    "epicDescription" : "Epic desc",
    "epicPriority" : "1",
    "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
    "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
    "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
    "levelOne" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d98879bd5641c754d2e6f"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 1",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "parentEpicId" : ObjectId("615d984e9bd5641c754d2e6e"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:27.706+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:27.706+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d988e9bd5641c754d2e70"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 12",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "parentEpicId" : ObjectId("615d984e9bd5641c754d2e6e"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:34.198+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:34.198+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "levelTwo" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d98a69bd5641c754d2e71"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 21",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "childTaskLevelOneId" : ObjectId("615d988e9bd5641c754d2e70"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:58.813+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:07:58.813+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "levelThree" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d98bf9bd5641c754d2e72"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 34",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "ChildTaskLevelTwoId" : ObjectId("615d98a69bd5641c754d2e71"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:23.404+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:23.404+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d98c79bd5641c754d2e73"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 35",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "ChildTaskLevelTwoId" : ObjectId("615d98a69bd5641c754d2e71"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:31.631+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:31.631+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("615d98d09bd5641c754d2e74"),
            "assignedPeople" : [
                ObjectId("613e40b419968b0652bbbb1e"),
                ObjectId("613e413619968b0652bbbb21")
            ],
            "isRemovedByOwner" : false,
            "highlightColorPreference" : "black",
            "isHidden" : false,
            "isDeleted" : false,
            "taskName" : "TASK name - 36",
            "taskDescription" : "Epic desc",
            "taskPriority" : "1",
            "startsFrom" : ISODate("2021-10-05T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "endsAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T14:36:31.387+05:30"),
            "createdBy" : ObjectId("613e418f19968b0652bbbb24"),
            "ChildTaskLevelTwoId" : ObjectId("615d98a69bd5641c754d2e71"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:40.071+05:30"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-10-06T18:08:40.071+05:30"),
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I just need to populate this `assignedPeople` and `createdBy` fields from Users collection. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided sample data (valid JSON data) to play with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53680441/populate-specific-fields-in-lookup may be similar to what you are looking for